# Using the squeeze theorem to prove a limit.

Tags: calculus, limits

I have to prove:

As $x$ approaches $0^+$, $f(x)$ approaches $0$, with $f(x) = \sqrt x  \cos^2(1/x)$.

I tried to begin by using the fact that $-1 \le \cos(1/x) \le 1$. After that I tried squaring everything which would result in $1 \le \cos(1/x) \le 1$ but that can't be correct I think??

The other option would be to multiply everything by $\sqrt x$ first, but then you would have to square everything after that, losing the $\sqrt x$ as it would become $x$.

So, how should I approach this problem?

Comment: If $-1\leq x\leq 1$ then $x^2 \leq 1$

Comment: @JonasGomes Thanks, I didn't notice that.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

Notice that as $x\to 0$, $\sqrt{x} \to 0$ and $\cos^2 \frac1x$ is bounded.

Answer (score 0):

$-1 \le \cos(1/{x}) \le 1$

$ |\cos^2(1/{x})| \le 1$

$ |\sqrt{x}  \cos^2(1/x)|\le \sqrt{x}$

Since $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \sqrt{x}=0$, by using squeeze theorem the function would approach zero also.